# Can't login using ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

All of a sudden I cannot login in to my MVC 5 app using ASP.NET identity. It was working perfectly for weeks and I changed nothing. I even created a BRAND NEW, default MVC project. I changed absolutely nothing. Again, I could register, but could NOT login. It keeps redirecting me to the home page.

I traced it through the DEFAULT code, listed here ....

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

It is successful and does hit this block of code ok....

```
SignInStatus.Success
```

If I recall, it worked until I installed Visual Studio 2017. But, I don't know if that was a coincidence or not.

I tried cleaning out asp.net cache/temp files and rebooting but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

**** UPDATE ***

Hmmm when I run the site in Chrome, INCOGNITO mode, it works. So, maybe it's a browser cache issue?

Comment: Do you see cookie set after redirect? Have you tried in another browser? Unlikely that VS2017 will make any difference to your existing project

Comment: Hmmm when I run the site in Chrome, INCOGNITO mode, it works. So, maybe it's a browser cache issue?

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 Did you find a solution to your problem? I'h having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry @Wolf, it was over 2 years ago. I dont remember details. But check out the "UPDATE" section in my OP.